# Grails: incompatibility between Spring Security Plugins?

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, google-signin

I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and I needed to add options to login via Facebook, Twitter and Google. I've added the following plugins to my BuildConfig.groovy file...

```
plugins {
....
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
compile ":spring-security-facebook:0.17"
compile ":spring-security-twitter:0.6"
```

And after setting numerous other parameters and adding the required gsp tags I can login/logout from Facebook and Twitter. To support Google login I've added the following plugins...

```
compile ":spring-security-oauth:2.1.0-RC4"
compile ':spring-security-oauth-google:0.3.1'
```

And I've added the required required parameters as specified in the [plugin docs](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth-google). Now if I try to login to Facebook or Twitter I get the following HTTP Status 404 errors in my browser when I click the login links:

```
message /TestSecurity/j_spring_twitter_security_check

description The requested resource is not available.
```

and...

```
message /TestSecurity/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect

description The requested resource is not available.
```

The Google login link doesn't produce the same error, but uses a different login link:

```
/TestSecurity/oauth/google/authenticate?redirectUrl
```

Can anyone explain why adding the plugins for Oauth/Google breaks the previous functionality and/or suggest a way to rectify it?

Here is the Debug output (as requested):

```
2015-03-12 12:56:02,601 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG twitter.DefaultTwitterAuthDao  - Init default Twitter Authentication Dao...
2015-03-12 12:56:02,617 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG twitter.DefaultTwitterAuthDao  - Twitter Authentication Dao is ready.
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/TestSecurity
....2015-03-12 12:56:22,834 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc41564: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-03-12 12:56:22,958 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc41564: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-03-12 12:56:23,427 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG facebook.FacebookAuthTagLib  - Do default server-side authentication redirect
2015-03-12 12:56:23,433 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG facebook.FacebookAuthTagLib  - Apply server side connect
2015-03-12 12:56:23,944 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc41564: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-03-12 12:56:23,944 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc41564: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
...
```

I've removed about a dozen lines from the end of the console output as they all contain the same information. When I login I have enabled the spring-security-ui module to override the default login page with the one provided by that module. When clicking the link to the login, the filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthentication output is generated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: looks like some conflict of the plugins. can you enable debug for all of them and put there output you'll get?

Comment: I don't know how to enable debug for all of them, I'm just getting started with Grails. Is there documentation somewhere? I can't find it in the plugin docs.

Comment: see http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/conf.html#logging and http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/guide/7%20Common%20Issues.html (for facebook and twitter)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov - have attached debug output as requested...

Comment: hard to say anything, don't see anything wrong there :( as well as nothing about hitting facebook filter. can you try to get facebook plugin example https://github.com/splix/grails-facebook-authentication-example and apply (minimum of) your changes? to check if it something with plugins or not